# Is there implicit argument name in React-native

Tags: react-native, indexing, label, implicit

I try to use the RadioButton lib in react-native, but I have some issue with the name of my variable/arguments and I'm not sure I understantd.

Here is the example code:

```
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      types2: [{label: 'param1', value: 0}, {label: 'param2', value: 1}, {label: 'param3', value: 2},],
      value2: 0,
      value2Index: 0,
    }
  }
```

```
 <RadioForm
              formHorizontal={true}
              animation={true}
            >
              {this.state.types2.map((obj, i) => {
                var that = this;
                var is_selected = this.state.value2Index == i;
                return (
                  <View key={i} style={styles.radioButtonWrap}>
                    <RadioButton
                      obj={obj}
                      index={i}
                      onPress={(value, index) => {
                        this.setState({value2:value})
                        this.setState({value2Index: index});
                      }}
                    />
                  </View>
                )
              })}
            </RadioForm>
```

There is a lot of things I can't figure out.
Here is my actual object:

```
 data: [{name: 'param1', number: 12}, {name: 'param2', number: 34}, {name: 'param3', number: 45},],
```

First, if I try to replace 'types2' object with my data, I have to rename the 'name' parameter to 'label'. Is it implicite that the name should be 'label' in your object? I can't keep the 'name' ?

Same thing for the 'value' parameter, If I dont have a value argument in my data, value2 will never be assigned, why?
why this wont work?:

```
  onPress={(number, index) => {
                        this.setState({value2:number})
 }}
```

The 'number' argument in my object is simply a data link with the name (not an id), but should I add a unique id in my object?

And finally, in the onPress function, I don't understand very well the 'index' variable. Is the second argument of onPress={(arg1, arg2)} will always be a generated index?

Also, in this code in don't understand the point of the 'value' parameter who is never used. We should use it as a key parameter in the RadioButton function instead of 'i', right?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can set the type2 state like

```
this.state = {
      types2: data.map(item => ({label: item.name, value:item.number})),
      value2: 0,
      value2Index: 0,
    }
```

If you are getting the data from response then use this.setState.

In the onPress function, you are getting the selected value and selected index. The first arg is selected value and the second arg is selected index.